# Patching deployments via kubernetes/client-go

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client, client-go

Having trouble figuring out what is wrong. I have a remote kubernetes cluster up and have copied the config locally. I know it is correct because I have gotten other commands to work for me.

The one I can't get to work is a deployment patch. My code:

```golang
const namespace = "default"
    
var clientset *kubernetes.Clientset

func init() {
    kubeconfig := "/Users/$USER/go/k8s-api/config"
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // create the clientset
    clientset, err = kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}

func main() {
    deploymentsClient := clientset.ExtensionsV1beta1().Deployments("default")

    patch := []byte(`[{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"my-deploy-test","image":"$ORG/$REPO:my-deploy0.0.1"}]}}}}]`)
    res, err := deploymentsClient.Patch("my-deploy", types.JSONPatchType, patch)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res)

}
```

All I get back is:
`panic: the server rejected our request due to an error in our request`

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you should use `types.StrategicMergePatchType` and remove leading (`[`) and trailing (`]`) brackets from patching string.

- **Merge patch:**

  > With a JSON merge patch, if you want to update a list, you have to specify the entire new list. And the new list completely replaces the existing list.

  [Source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-json-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment)
- **Strategic merge patch:**

  > With a strategic merge patch, a list is either replaced or merged depending on its patch strategy. The patch strategy is specified by the value of the `patchStrategy` key in a field tag in the Kubernetes source code. For example, the `Containers` field of `PodSpec` struct has a `patchStrategy` of `merge`:
  >
  > ```golang
  > type PodSpec struct {
  >   ...
  >   Containers []Container `json:"containers" patchStrategy:"merge" patchMergeKey:"name" ...`
  > ```

  [Source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#notes-on-the-strategic-merge-patch)

N.B. `kubectl` by default uses strategic merge patch to patch Kubernetes resources.

Comment: So, I have tried both methods and it seems that StrategicMergePatchType looks for the first matching tag, in this case containers[0].name and then merges that, but if the patched name does not match containers[0].name then it adds a new container object into the array. Does this sound correct? Why would I want this instead of MergePatchType?

Comment: Edited my answer and following link has some more useful informations.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#notes-on-the-strategic-merge-patch

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thank you for clearing that up! Accepting this as the answer.

Comment: For non list fields, what is the logic of using strategy merge patch or merge patch? such as nodeselector which type is map.

Comment: @AbuHanifa - Great answer, I want to patch the node condition type, I am not sure how to get the right struct []byte to use for the patch.

Answer (score 6):

You have mixed up [`JSONPatchType with MergePatchType`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types#PatchType); `JSONPatchType` wants the input to be [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.3) formatted "commands", and in that case can be a JSON array, because there can be multiple commands applied in order to the input document

However, your payload looks much closer to you wanting `MergePatchType`, in which case the input should **not** be a JSON array because the source document is not an array of `"spec"` objects.

Thus, I'd bet just dropping the leading `[` and trailing `]`, changing the argument to be `types.MergePatchType` will get you much further along

Comment: Works! Any comments on MergePatchType vs StrategicMergePatchType? Some info on my comment above.

Comment: I am trying to patch a node condition type, not sure how to do that.

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in the comments of other questions; asking new questions is free